# How to convert the users input to a string

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is the code for the textbox that the user inputs to

```
self.sentemail = tkinter.Entry(self.master)
self.sentemail["width"] = 60
self.sentemail.focus_set()
self.sentemail.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

I want to be able to use what they type in, hence wanting to put it into a string variable. For example, if they typed in "Hello" and when its inserted into a string variable called myvar, i want to be able to do:

```
print (myvar)
```

and it prints out "Hello".

Im using Python 3.4. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is copied from a program I wrote:

```
self._text_entry = Entry() #could also be Text()
#something in between
self.index_name = self.text_entry.get(1.0, END).rstrip('\n')
```

I believe this is still the correct method in Python 3.

Edit: https://github.com/dlawre14/gatk-automator/blob/master/source_files/gatk_bwa_popups.py that has some code implementing the Text widget.

Comment: @SteMain I just reviewed my code and this is for a Text() object. I found those are a bit more flexible than Entry().

Comment: Any idea how i would change it to a text object?

Comment: @SteMain Instead of making an Entry, do self.sentemail = tkinter.Text() Here's a link to some code I wrote using tkinter: https://github.com/dlawre14/gatk-automator/blob/master/source_files/gatk_bwa_popups.py

Comment: Your answer is a bit misleading:if you call `.get(...)` immediately after creating the widget you won't get anything, since the widget is empty. Your example would be better if you somehow separate those two statements (eg: show a function tied to a button or event that calls `.get(...)`)

Comment: @BryanOakley Yeah, I was just illustrating the methods, I have changed the post a bit and linked to the file on git that I've been referencing.

Comment: After ivbe changed it to text, it crashes when i add the line of code self.index_name = self.sentemail.get()

Comment: @SteMain: the documentation on the text and entry widgets shows you how to get the contents. It is not the same for each widget.